# Basic grid for xna?

Tags: c#, xna, grid

I was wondering if it possible to somehow make a simple grid (like the one you would see in 3ds max or other 3d designing software)

I will need it only when debugging and checking out xna 4.0

Edit:
grid in 3d environment

Comment: I meant reference grid. http://uppix.net/f/c/f/e61017eac9f708b55622e9d21c2bb.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a grid component [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shader_series_3) which is very good.  I use it as it is a really good way for debugging purposes.

Comment: A shame it is only available for XNA 4.0

Comment: Link is broken (Thanks to brilliant Microsoft site update). Correct link is http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shader_series_3

Answer (score 0):

You could create a quad for each axis' plane. Texture the quad with a grid textur that is transparent between the grid lines. By making the center grid lines bold and positioning the quad just right, you can get all 3 grids (if you want more than one) to line up perfectly at the world origin.

It can be heavy for the pixel shader in that every pixel on the screen will be involved, but if it is just for developmment only, you'll be OK.